# How to keep a Fancybox fixed to the viewport top, even on small viewports

Tags: javascript, fancybox, fixed, fancybox-2

### The Problem:

When dealing with small viewports (smaller than the iframe), Fancybox changes from Fixed, to Absolute position. On large screens the iframe is fixed to the center of the screen, but on smaller screens (even smaller than the iframe by one pixel) the user can suddenly scroll down the hosting page, and lose sight of the iframe.

### What have I tried:

As far as I can tell it happens because of this piece of code:

```
if (current.autoCenter && current.fixed && !onlyAbsolute && height <= viewport.h && width <= viewport.w) {
    rez.position = 'fixed';

} else if (!current.locked) {
    rez.top  += viewport.y;
    rez.left += viewport.x;
}
```

deleting the last two conditions (`height <= viewport.h && width <= viewport.w`) fixes the problem, but I wish to avoid tampering with the original source code.

Any combination of the following options is either not relevant, or has bad or no effect: `fixed`, `scrolling`, `fitToView`, `scrollOutside`.

### The question:

Is there any hidden / available option that I missed that can force the Fancybox iframe to be **always** attached to the top of the viewport?

EDIT: Or better yet, is there a way to make the outside scroll to scroll by the iframe size? Meaning, just enough to reveal the entire iframe, but not more than that, so that the iframe doesn't get hidden.

Comment: what device/browser/os shows this behavior? ... what do you call "iframe": is fancybox opening an external page with `type: "iframe"`?

Comment: All browsers. By iframe I mean the window that Fancybox opens. To be more exact, the element that is either `fixed` or `absolute` is the outermost div. In my case it has the following classes: `fancybox-wrap fancybox-desktop fancybox-type-iframe fancybox-opened`.

Comment: If you are using the latest version and have not disabled the locked feature, then scrolling the page should not scroll the page - http://jsfiddle.net/Anadm/3/

Comment: @Janis - You are opening the iframe with AutoHeight - If your height is dynamically changing, and always smaller than the viewport height, ofcourse it won't scroll.

Comment: I still do not understand - http://jsfiddle.net/Anadm/4/ - the page is not scrolling if the frame is larger. Please, create an example.

Comment: Even on your example, the iframe position is absolute, and if you scroll down, you lose sight of the top of the iframe.